# WinForms and WPF in the same project?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I'm looking for a bit of enlightenment... I started working on a project in WPF and came across a need for some old code I had written in WinForms. I had expected a warning of some type because of what I assumed to be vast differences between the two platforms, but I decided to import a few code files from the WinForms project into the new WPF project just to see what would happen. Note that both the WinForms code and WPF code are in the same project, they are compiled into the same assembly. Expecting an error, I was not only surprised that I could import it, but the code worked correctly. Sure they're both written in C# and .Net 4.0, but I didn't realize WPF and WinForms could coexist like this.

I am obviously misunderstanding the way these frameworks work, can somebody explain how these frameworks can coexist in the same assembly without conflicting?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't much difference between WPF and Winforms, really.  They both use HWNDs to hold their content.  They both use a message pump.  They both resolve down to Win32 calls for most things.  WPF and Winforms both use resources.  Accessing both produces IL code.  They just reference different base assemblies, but those base assemblies can coexist just as you can use both System.Xml and System.IO in the same module.

The major differences are internal such as the drawing/rendering method, but you can display your Winforms content inside WPF with the [WinFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The only time you will see issues is when you are trying to host WPF content in an old-school `Form` or attempting to host a WinForm control in a WPF `Window`. Outside of that scenario, they both compile down to perfectly valid IL, which is all .NET needs to generate the correct machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, WPF and Winforms are both presentation layer technologies in Windows Application Dev. They're just 2 different parts of the same framework - .Net Framework.

According to Wikipedia:

[WinForms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)

> Winforms is the name given to the graphical application programming
>   interface (API) included as a part of Microsoft .NET Framework,
>   providing access to native Microsoft Windows interface elements by
>   wrapping the extant Windows API in managed code.

[WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)

> the Windows Presentation Foundation (or WPF) is a computer-software
>   graphical subsystem for rendering user interfaces in Windows-based
>   applications. WPF, previously known as "Avalon", was initially
>   released as part of .NET Framework 3.0. Rather than relying on the
>   older GDI subsystem, WPF uses DirectX.

And the following pic may show you a cleaner view about their relationship.
[image: .Net Framework]